# Why is it when I load an “embedded” facebook post on my webpage it loads very slow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

**Problem:**

So I have a simple webpage that has embedded youtube videos and 1 facebook posts. The youtube videos load fine thats besides the point but when I put the embedded facebook post on my page it took forever for the “facebook post” to load on the page. Let alone the fact that it did NOT even load on mobile.

**How I got the embedded facebook post:**

I just simply went to a post on facebook and clicked the top right arrow and they have an option of  “embed post” which then gives me a code to put on my site. And it gave me this.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0" data-width="300"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0"><p>Live to tweet about it. #SANANDREAS #NowPlaying</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie">San Andreas</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0">Sunday, June 14, 2015</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

**(index) My Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Theme</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, initial-scale=0.3">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<header></header>

<!—embedded facebook post that loads terrible for some reason—>
<div class="eq-content fb-content”><!— this container has a large background image with the width of 2000px—>
<div class="dynamic-content-3">
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0" data-width="300"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0"><p>Live to tweet about it. #SANANDREAS #NowPlaying</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie">San Andreas</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sanandreasmovie/posts/816703421758294:0">Sunday, June 14, 2015</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
</div>

<footer> </footer>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I cannot provide an example link at the moment because im having server problems. But anyways I don’t believe an example is really required. The concept is pretty straight forward you can just have a div with a large background image like I have and in the middle generate your embedded facebook post and you will see the same thing I am seeing. Also like I said it rarely loads on mobile and loads extremely slow for me on my IMAC (desktop).

I have no clue why facebook would ever make it like this when it takes an unreasonable amount of time to load but the only possible solution I can thing ok is maybe have like some type of javascript pre-loader so I can load the page first and then display the content. Thats just a little idea I had but any other solutions/ideas will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Facebook likebox on my site load pretty slow, look like it only start to load when page load finished? (In your case maybe that's Facebook CDN problems, how about loading time when you visit Facebook?)

Comment: Facebook it self loads fine its just the embedded post on my webpage. Not the webpage it self the webpage loads fine but the embedded post itself take veeery long to load and doesn't even load on mobile.

Comment: Read the tag descriptions before adding.

Comment: If you want a slow site, add Facebook and Twitter feeds. Just how it is implementing all their 3rd party checks and balances.

Comment: @cswl iv already tried that.

Comment: @user2782001 So no way around it even with Iframes?

Comment: The same loads pretty fast for me on https://www.fbrell.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try the below link. Generally embedded videos/posts grabs the entire data from the hosts, thus the load time.
However, using some JS you can fix this (Its actually a hack)
So you make a div which shows an image for the video, it should seem to the user that it is the actual video.
Once the video div is clicked, make a js call to replace the div content to the actual embed post.

This helps a lot in load time of the entire page if you want to show a lot of embedded posts.

https://medium.com/@BenBillups/facebook-video-embeds-that-actually-work-57037f8cdcf3

Cheers. :)